# How to get support emails to thead properly with Drupal's Support Ticketing System module

Tags: drupal-6

I am using the Support Ticketing System module (6.x-1.x-dev) I have written a support request in the issues section for the module, but have not received any help yet.  My post is here http://drupal.org/node/902262 I am having trouble getting newly received emails to match against existing tickets.  This module has an option to "Thread emails using mail headers" on its settings page.  That seems to work for most situations, however, for my case, the customer support emails are generated from support requests sent to our eBay store.  (The customer contacts the seller through eBay's internal messaging, then eBay emails a copy of the customer message to the seller)  It seems that the email message headers generated by eBay will not allow for the proper matching of messages with existing tickets.  If I disable "Thread emails using mail headers" option and use the default "Thread emails using subject" new tickets will not match against existing ones because "Re:" is in the subject of replied to messages.

My first thought was to try and strip out the string "Re:" from the subject of messages.  There is a hook for this module that allows for performing custom processing when receiving emails. (details of the hook are in my support request) I received some help from drupal irc for some php code to use in the hook.   The hook was able to successfully strip out the "RE:" string in the subjects, however, the emails still would not thread properly.

I looked at the support.module code and found the section between lines 2843 to 2941 to have logic for matching new emails to existing tickets.  I pasted the code here drupalbin.com/16005

In the code comments posted, I noted sections are divided by letter A through E.  For my case, it looks like I really don't need matching to work for A, B, C, D,.  I would need it to work for E. Any thoughts on how I can get a match for message subject despite the "Re:" string my modifying the posted code?

Answer (score 0):

The following comment to thread in the issues section for the module solved this problem.

http://drupal.org/node/902262#comment-3433792